# EController login isn't working anymore in IBM Content Manager 8.4

Tags: java, servlets

I've got EController working like a charm in IBM CM 8.3. When I upgraded to 8.4 I saw that the idm.jar has been modified and that IDMConnection doesn't do a request forward any more but a redirect.

I've fixed that by putting params as a session attribute. But now when I login through EController and display my search results, I don't have the right permission, even when I pass the credentials of icmadmin.

The following url did work ik 8.3 :
`"/IDMConnection?server=" + "name=" + strServerName + ",type=" + strServerType + "&userid=" + strUserID + "&password=" + strPassword + "&action=Login"`

Do I need to send more params to it? I'm quite stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, the problem is that since 8.4 there is a browser issues with IE. So you need to provide the browser as a connection param. Like:

```
"/IDMConnection?server=" + "name=" + strServerName + ",type=" + strServerType + "&userid=" + strUserID + "&password=" + strPassword + "&browser=ie4&action=Login"
```

Now it works.....

How did I figured it out?
Well, I re-routed the IDMLogon2.jsp to a custom filter, there I debugged/printed-out all the params and there it was :). It even has an extra param, platform=win, but that one is not necessary.